# Sideloaded UWP app is launching the older version of the app previously installed by another user

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, sideloading

The app I'm working on is a sideloaded UWP app. There are 2 users of the tablet/computer. User1 installed an older version of the UWP sideloaded app. And User2 installed the older version and then updated to a newer version. User2 has been using the updated app for a while. After a couple of weeks, when launching the UWP app on the second user, it launches the older version instead of the new one.

I'm suspicious that there's something happening in the windows update. All of the tablets that has this issue has recently updated windows. Particularly having KB4489899. But I'm still not sure if that's actually the cause.

The workaround for this is to reinstall the app. But it still didn't explain why the version was reverted to the older one.

Update: 
Tried to reinstall the current version as a workaround. But few weeks later it reverted back again to the previous version.

Comment: This is difficult to diagnose, we are not sure if this patch update will cause the app's version to roll back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same issue happen to us and all affected devices had KB4489899 update in Windows event log. From what we can tell, the side loaded application is uninstalled from "User2" after KB4489899 and upon launch by User2 the older version is "installed". If you go to settings for User2 you will see the re-installed older app size is tiny because it's referencing the install from User1.

Our fix was to re-install but we don't know if same issue will occur with future another Windows update. To prevent issue our team is going to proactively find and uninstall(via script) older versions of sideloaded apps when we update our KIOSK software. This is not scalable so hopefully Microsoft can resolve.

Comment: I think that's the best way to go, just uninstall the older version.

Comment: It turns out that we can't uninstall the current version because it wipes out the local state and we can't do that.